# Prima tabulação para pesquisar

Tags: javascript, html

Alguém sabe como faço para quando o usuário colocar o meu site na barra do Google Chrome, o navegador apresentar a mensagem "Prima tabulação para pesquisar em [endereço do site]" e depois quando o usuário clicasse no ENTER ele passasse os parâmetros assim ?query=[texto]

[image: Exemplo com o YT]

Comment: "Adicionar a barra" seria adicionar aos favoritos?

Comment: não tem nada a ver

Comment: Então não entendi, poderia explicar melhor por favor